# Got an error while running an app (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tornado.ioloop')

Tags: python, cmd, tornado, streamlit

I got the error on running the following code
streamlit run app.py

Then I used a virtual environment and installed streamlit and started the app again but got the same error again.

I tried installing tornado but it says Requirement already satisfied( As you can see in the screenshot)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tornado.ioloop' is the last error traceback.[image]

Comment: I'm not a `conda` user, but I don't think it's a good idea to mix `pip` and `conda`. If you install anything with `conda`, I think you need to install everything with it. (or you can avoid `conda` and use `pip` and `venv` for everything)

Comment: Nope thats not it. You are saying this because you are not using conda. Conda install is not able to install so many python libraries because their codes are not present in the anaconda cloud packages but we can still use them by using pip. Actually I was able to solve the above issue check out the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem. Actually the problem comes because of unsupported versions of streamlit and its dependencies. Follow along if you are facing the same issue and are using conda. So all I did was to uninstall and reinstall these mentioned libraties in the same order as done. streamlit, tornado, plotly, cufflinks and pydeck. (Using pip uninstall  ... ).

Then reinstall in any order but make sure to 'pip install streamlit' at the last as it will install all those versions of the previous libraries that are compatible with it. You can use a virtual environment also for the same but again make sure to install streamlit at the last.

Thats all, thanks.